# Screenshot always returning as a white image on iOS using robovm and libgdx

Tags: libgdx, ios, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot for sharing on social media.  This code works on my Desktop project, but when I use it on iOS it always shows up as a white image, I am using the standard libgdx code for the screenshot factory, any suggestions?

```
public class ScreenShotFactory 
{
public static void SaveScreenshot()
{
    try
    {
        Gdx.files.local("shot.png").delete();
        FileHandle fh;
        do
        {
            fh = new FileHandle(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath() + "shot.png");
        }
        while (fh.exists());

        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);

        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);

        pixmap.dispose();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {           
    }
}

private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean yDown)
{
    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);

    if (yDown) 
    {
        // Flip the pixmap upside downx
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }
        pixels.clear();
        pixels.put(lines);
        pixels.clear();
    }
    Logger.Log("ScreenShot Taken!");
    return pixmap;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2632) is related and offers a solution

The solution is to do the screenshot in iOS specific code:

```
public byte[] takeScreenshot(){
UIImage newImage;
UIGraphics.beginImageContext(new CGSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
application.getUIViewController().getView().drawViewHierarchy(
      new CGRect(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) , true);
newImage = UIGraphics.getImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.endImageContext();  

NSData data = newImage.toJPEGData(.6);
newImage.dispose();

return data.getBytes();
}
```

only problem is converting the returned data to a pixmap, which I havent figured out yet(because I dont know the format toJPEGData writes in)